# Is it bad to make p12 file of developer cerificate public?

Tags: ios, certificate

I want to put the private key of my app's developer certificate under version control. Is this a wrong thing to do? After all, that certificate only allows me to debug my app locally, nothing can be uploaded to itunes without production certificate, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep the key private to protect your own device.

Disregarding whether you think the following attack "would" happen, it's still something you don't want to be possible.

If an attacker gets the key and can debug your app locally, they could then use any permission you've granted to the development copy of the app.

There are other hurdles to carrying out the attack, of course. But keeping the private key to yourself is one of the strongest defenses.

Comment: So development private key is useless without my device?

Comment: If you've been careful not to use this key for anything else, then your device is the only one that trusts it for anything.

Comment: Thank you. Right now losing my unlocked device is as bad for me as locked, so there'so no point in keeping dev key a secret.